# php-created rss feed has encoding errors since on new server

Tags: php, encoding, rss

After moving a website from one webserver (Apache 1.3) to another (Apache 2.0 at domainfactory), the W3C feed validator says the feed is correct but has two problems:

1. Feeds should not be served with the "text/plain" media type
2. Your feed appears to be encoded as "ISO-8859-1", but your server is reporting "US-ASCII"
   php-created rss feed

The help link didn't help.

Firefox and Chrome show the source code instead of the nice feed view (other feeds are shown correctly).

We are using php 5.3.6 to generate the feed: http://www.stuttmann-karikaturen.de/feed.rss. It's generated as a file, not on-the-fly.

We have tried adding (alternatively) the following lines to .htaccess:

- AddType application/rss+xml .xml
- AddType application/xml .xml
- AddType text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1 .xml

No change. Any ideas?

---

Kwebbles answer did it for me. In case someone has a similar problem, here's the correct AddType line that worked:

`AddType text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1 rss`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the extension of the resource is .rss I think the AddType directives should also use that.

Comment: Very true (quite blind not to see that). And guess what: AddType text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1 rss did it! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.htaccess`, use a PHP [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to make those settings.

Comment: Can't do that (or have to change a lot of things) because the rss file is generated one time and not created on-the-fly, so there is no chance to add a header.